# Python Selenium return text, unicode object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, typeerror, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate some web browsing. Currently I'm trying to access a specific element by class name and return the text within it (the element im selecting on the page definetly has text in it) and when I try to return it in my function I get

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

My code for the function is as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("my chromedriver installation path")
driver.get("website URL")

def getText():
    return driver.find_element_by_class_name("class with text").text()

print getText()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`.text`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) is **not a method**, it is an attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("class with text").text
```